# Isometry in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> Show that any element $g$ in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ is an isometry in $\mathbb R^3$

$\operatorname{SO}(3) = \{ g \in M(3,\mathbb R) \mid gg^t = I, \ \det(g) =1 \}$

where $M(3,\mathbb R)$ is the set of matrices $3\times3$ in $\mathbb R$, and $I$ is the identity matrix.

**My answer is:**

$\|gx\|^2  =\langle gx,gx\rangle = g \langle x,gx \rangle = gg^t \langle x,x \rangle = \langle x,x \rangle$

Is my answer true?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

We need to show that distances are preserved that is

$$|gx-gy|^2=|g(x-y)|^2=\langle g(x-y),g(x-y) \rangle=[g(x-y)]^Tg(x-y)=\\=(x-y)^Tg^Tg(x-y)=(x-y)^T(x-y)=\langle x-y,x-y \rangle=|x-y|^2$$

and thus we can conclude that every linear (or affine) transformation with orthogonal matrix is an isometry.